# ASP.NET MVC - value being send to controller is null from the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can't seem to figure out why my value being send to the controller using `Html.BeginForm()` is always NULL.

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SearchTest(string searchThingy)
{
        try
        {
            var model = new SearchTestViewModel(searchThingy);
            return PartialView("_SearchTest", model);
        }
        catch
        {
            return PartialView("_Error");
        }
}
```

This is the code I am using to call the controller in the view:

```
// The component containing the value in the view:
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchThingy, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtSearchTerm" })

// This Ajax.BeginForm is being called from a button
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchTest", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = FormMethod.Post.ToString(),
    OnBegin = "showGeneralLoadingIndicator",
    OnComplete = "hideGeneralLoadingIndicator"
}, new { @id = "frmSearchOutstandingActions" }))
{@Html.Hidden("searchThingy", Model.SearchThingy)}

// I have also tried using query string instead:
@{var queryStringParameters = new { @searchThingy = Model.SearchThingy }; }

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchTest", "Search", queryStringParameters, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = FormMethod.Post.ToString(),
    OnBegin = "showGeneralLoadingIndicator",
    OnComplete = "hideGeneralLoadingIndicator"
}, new { @id = "frmSearchOutstandingActions" }))
{}
```

My view model code relevant to this:

```
public class SearchTestViewModel
{
    public string SearchThingy{ get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried changing the `HttpMethod` to a get. I can't understand why

Comment: try this `<input type="hidden" name="searchThingy4" value='@Model.SearchThingy'/>`

Comment: If you use your browser dev tools, is there a value being posted from the Ajax.BeginForm or is it empty? Also, you can inspect your view and check the value in the "searchThingy" hidden input. When the view is first rendered, the Model.SearchThingy value is placed in that hidden input. If you are not updating that hidden inputs value before posting the form (you haven't shared that code), that could be the issue.

Comment: @viveknuna Tried the input still no work. Browser dev tools shows there is a value being posted.

Comment: So you are posting value? But how can you get in parameter then?

Comment: Post more of your view